# Fetch value of a specific Key from dataLayer Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-datalayer

A website stores a lot of parameters into dataLayer google analytics and inside one of my  javascript functions, I am thinking of using one of the parameters and used below code to iterate between the properties

```
    var articleId=0;
    var brandId=-1;
    $.each( dataLayer, function( key, value ) {
      console.log( key + ": " + JSON.stringify(value) );
    });
```

some of the values from  `JSON.stringify(value)` are like below

```
    {"BrandID":0}
    {"BrandName":"  Group"}
    {"Title":"  announces electric   cranes"}
    {"PageType":"Article"}
    {"ArticleID":8009988}
    {"ArticleTitle":"  announces electric   cranes"}
    {"ArticleLayout":"Standard"}
    {"ArticleTypeID":"1"}
    {"ArticleTypeName":"Article"}
    .......................................
```

and many more

How can I fetch the BrandID and ArticleID out of this?
Is there any way of doing this without iterating through all the items of dataLayer

Answer (score 0):

There's a built in method in the google tag manager api to get values:

```js
google_tag_manager['<container-id>'].dataLayer.get('gtm.start');
```

The `container-id` is that of your GTM container, something like `GTM-XXXXXXX`

**Edit**: for getting values from multiple containers on one page, you can loop through each container after getting their ID's:

Something like:

```js
const containerIds = Object.keys(google_tag_manager).filter(key => key.includes('GTM-'));

const values = containerIds.map(id => google_tag_manager[id].dataLayer.get('gtm.start'));

console.log(values); // [value1, value2, ...]
```

Comment: Unfortunately there are multiple containerIDs exists in page

Comment: edited with a quick example of how you can loop through multiple containers. It's in ES6, as I'm not familiar with jQuery but the same could be done with jQuery I'm sure